# Using case with count as one of conditions in SQL query

Tags: postgresql, count, case

I'm trying to generate new table with select statement from another table

Given table(name: business):

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

CREATE TABLE business (
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    name text NOT NULL,
    brand text
);


INSERT INTO business (name, brand) VALUES
('Auchan' , NULL),
('Auchan' , NULL),
('Auchan' , NULL),
('Auchan' , NULL),
('Auchan' , NULL),
('Auchan' , NULL),
('EpicHd' , NULL),
('Kafkflef' , 'Kafk');
```

I want to create a new table with condition if occurrences of name is more than 5 for example.
The select statement looks like this:

```
SELECT
       uuid_generate_v4 () as uuid,
       name as name,
       CASE
           WHEN brand IS NOT NULL
               THEN brand
           WHEN brand IS NULL AND count(name) > 5
               THEN name
           ELSE 'Other'
       END as brand,
       CURRENT_DATE as time_added
FROM business;
```

But I got ERROR: column "brand" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

And when I added this GROUP BY brand, I got another error but to add GROUP BY with name and so on with other columns, that I didn't include here.

Can someone please help me and put me on the right track? Thank you.

Comment: You should folllow every error hint, you'll get something. When you `count`, it is over a group of things, and postgresql must know what things. Hence the need of a `group by` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow postgres' hints, you must use a group by:

```sql
BEGIN;

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

CREATE TABLE business (
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    name text NOT NULL,
    brand text
);


INSERT INTO business (name, brand) VALUES
('Auchan' , NULL),
('Auchan' , NULL),
('Auchan' , NULL),
('Auchan' , NULL),
('Auchan' , NULL),
('Auchan' , NULL),
('EpicHd' , NULL),
('Kafkflef' , 'Kafk');

SELECT
    uuid_generate_v4 () AS uuid,
    name AS name,
    CASE WHEN brand IS NOT NULL THEN
        brand
    WHEN brand IS NULL
        AND count(name) > 5 THEN
        name
    ELSE
        'Other'
    END AS brand,
    CURRENT_DATE AS time_added
FROM
    business
GROUP BY name, brand;

ROLLBACK;
```

Result:

```
f6a66b5d-fd43-4deb-be14-f052ddc142b2    Auchan  Auchan  2021-07-30
fbfd60ee-5c28-407f-8c46-21716a2e98a7    EpicHd  Other   2021-07-30
275a6d4c-6859-4a6c-a917-b818cf142809    Kafkflef    Kafk    2021-07-30
```